# Dynamically insert multiple documents using mgo golang mongodb

Tags: database, mongodb, go, nosql, mgo

How can I insert an array of documents into MongoDB with [mgo](https://godoc.org/labix.org/v2/mgo) library using only a **single** DB call as in [db.collection.insert()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insert/#insert-multiple-documents)?

I have the following `Transaction` structure:

```
    type Transaction struct {
    Brand         string `json:"brand"`
    Name          string `json:"name"`
    Plu           string `json:"plu"`
    Price         string `json:"price"`
  }
```

From a `POST` request I will recieve an array of these structures. I want to insert them into MongoDB as *individual* documents but using a single DB call as explained in [db.collection.insert()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insert/#insert-multiple-documents)

I tried using [`c.Insert`](https://godoc.org/labix.org/v2/mgo#Collection.Insert) of mgo

The following is the code snippet:

```
  func insertTransaction(c *gin.Context) {
    var transactions []Transaction
    err := c.BindJSON(&transactions)
    if err != nil {
        c.AbortWithStatusJSON(http.StatusBadRequest, map[string]string{"error":"invalid JSON"})
        return
    }
    err = InsertTransactons(transactions)
    if err != nil {
        c.AbortWithStatusJSON(http.StatusInternalServerError, &map[string](interface{}){
            "status":  "error",
            "code":    "500",
            "message": "Internal server error",
            "error": err,
        })
        return
    }
    c.JSON(http.StatusCreated, &map[string](interface{}){
        "status":  "success",
        "code":    "0",
        "message": "created",
    })
  }


  func InsertTransactons(u []Transaction) error {
    s := GetSession()
    defer s.Close()
    c := s.DB(DB).C(TransactionColl)
    err := c.Insert(u...)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
  }
```

But as I compile and run the code, I get the following error:

> go/database.go:34:17: cannot use u (type *[]Transaction) as type
>   []interface {} in argument to c.Insert

Comment: As the error says you are trying to insert pointer to Transaction slice. Though `Collection.Insert()` takes `[]interface{}` not `*[]interface{}`

Comment: @Himanshu I tried removing the pointer and still the error

Comment: what is error after removing pointer to interface

Comment: There are no `bson:""` tags for your transaction struct.

Comment: @Himanshu Strangely it works without `bson` tag

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You cannot pass `[]*Transaction` as `[]interface{}`. You need to convert each `Transaction` to `inferface{}` to change its memory layout.

```
var ui []interface{}
for _, t := range u{
    ui = append(ui, t)
}
```

Pass ui to `c.Insert` instead

Comment: Thanks dude..It worked! I wish if there was no need for a `range`

Comment: when answers do not use the same variable/constant names as questions, it becomes VERY confusing for users trying to make use of the answers later..where did `ui` come from?

Comment: @uberrebu "ui" is just an array of interfaces defined to include all the items converted to interface. You can rename it to anything.

Answer (score 3):

Create slice of interface for document structs by appending and then inserting data using Bulk insert which takes variable arguments.

```
type Bulk struct {
    // contains filtered or unexported fields
}
func (b *Bulk) Insert(docs ...interface{})
```

For inserting documents in [Bulk](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/mgo.v2#Bulk.Insert)

```
const INSERT_COUNT int = 10000

type User struct {
    Id    bson.ObjectId `bson:"_id,omitempty" json:"_id"`
    Email string        `bson:"email" json:"email"`
}

func (self *User) Init() {
    self.Id = bson.NewObjectId()
}
```

Call `Bulk()` function on collection returned from db connection. `Bulk()` function returns pointer to `*Bulk`.

```
bulk := dbs.Clone().DB("").C("users").Bulk()
bulk.Insert(users...)
```

Assign it to variable which will be used to call `Insert()` method using `Bulk` pointer receiver.

```
func main(){
    // Database
    dbs, err := mgo.Dial("mongodb://localhost/")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    // Collections
    uc := dbs.Clone().DB("").C("users")
    defer dbs.Clone().DB("").Session.Close()
    for n := 0; n < b.N; n++ {
        count := INSERT_COUNT
        users := make([]interface{}, count)
        for i := 0; i < count; i++ {
            loop_user := User{}
            loop_user.Init()
            loop_user.Email = fmt.Sprintf("report-%d@example.com", i)
            users[i] = loop_user
        }
        bulk := uc.Bulk()
        bulk.Unordered()
        bulk.Insert(users...)
        _, bulkErr := bulk.Run()
        if bulkErr != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Actually I wouldn't wanted to use `bulk` update as `insert` already supports multiple documents. Anyway I will refer this for bulk update